# AssertJ error reporting fails due to a circular reference with toString()

Tags: java, junit, lombok, assertj

Legacy code to be tested has circular references so something like many-to-one bidirectional relationship entities.

Unfortunately there are also Lombok annotations `@ToString` & `@Data` in related classes which then result into a stack overflow whenever `toString()` is called.

Of course I realize that this is a bit bad code and if `toString()` methods really are needed there should be some agreement and needed fields should be annotated with `@ToString.Exclude` to prevent circular reference with `toString()`. However it is not currently up to me to touch this code but I still would like to use **AssertJ**, for example like:

```
assertThat(list1).containsExactly(item1, item2);
```

instead of doing some more complicated testing code.

The problem now is that instead of **AssertJ** reporting assertion failure the test *execution* fails because this circular reference when AssertJ calls `toString()` on items to report what were the failing items.

Is it possible and if then how can I change AssertJ to report failures without calling the `toString()` but - for example - `getId()` on failing items?

Comment: Would you have the chance to share a reproducible example?

Comment: There is a method that causes a stack overflow and you're not fixing it? Seriously, this is not "a bit bad code". It's a time bomb. Fix it now, don't work around it.

Comment: @StefanoCordio I'll add example later.

Comment: @JanRieke You are absolutely correct but if this is not in my hands or if using some buggy external library. Anyway I'm interested about the possibility to configure AssertJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use a Custom representation for the lists:
Assuming the class `Obj` which has circular reference to it's `toString()`. Define a custom representation class as:

```java
class CustomListRepresentation implements Representation {
    public static final CustomListRepresentation instance = new CustomListRepresentation();
    
    private CustomListRepresentation() {
    }
    @Override
    public String toStringOf(Object) {
        List<?> list = (List<?>) object;
        return list.stream()
                   .filter(Obj.class::isInstance)
                   .map(Obj.class::cast).map(Obj::getId)
                   .map(String::valueOf)
                   .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }

    @Override
    public String unambiguousToStringOf(Object object) {
        return this.toStringOf(object);
    }

}
```

If multiple classes other than `Obj` also have this issue then you could keep a map of these classes along with their mapping functions (to be used instead of `toString()`) can be defined and replace the `.filter(Obj.class::isInstance).map(Obj.class::cast).map(Obj::getId)` appropriately.

Now the assert statement need to be modified as:

```java
assertThat(list).withRepresentation(CustomListRepresentation.instance)
                .containsExactly(item1, item2);
```

---

Or a different way would be to override the error message using the `overridingErrorMessage` method:

```java
private static String getError(List<Obj> list, Obj... items) {
    // return a custom formatted error message.....
}
```

Assert as:

```java
assertThat(list).overridingErrorMessage(getError(list, item1, item2))
                .containsExactly(item1, item2);
```

Comment: Nice! Seems exactly what is needed. I will check this during weekend.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69040649/6413377) my final (until these annoying circularities are refactored away) was simple as:

```
Representation pres = new StandardRepresentation() {
    public String toStringOf(Object object) {
        return unambiguousToStringOf(object);
    }
    public String unambiguousToStringOf(Object object) {
        return (object == null) ? "null" : object.getClass().getSimpleName() + "@" + object.hashCode();
    }
};
```

and in my test just something like (with a stupid example class):

```
@ToString
public static class A {
    public A a;
}

@Test
void testNoError() {
    var a = new A();
    a.a = a;
    // Not null so AssretJ prints out failing object when test fails
    assertThat(a).withRepresentation(pres).isNull();
}
```